# Why does Supergirl's Fortress of Solitude look so different from Superman's?

Tags: arrowverse, supergirl, superman-and-lois

In the *Supergirl* episode *Welcome Back, Kara!*, Supergirl explicitly states that the Fortress is the same one Kal-el uses, but from all visual indications it's clearly not. Her version is more decorated, more open and spacious, and prominently displays Kryptonian technology, whereas the set they use on *Superman and Lois* is quite sparse by comparison and has a similar but distinctly different "look-and-feel" to it.

It seems like it has to be intentional; if both shows are being made by the same studio, (which they are, and both are filmed in Vancouver, BC to boot,) it would not only improve consistency to re-use the established set, it would save money too!  But they went and built an entirely new one for *Superman and Lois.*

Do we have any explanation for this?

Comment: I don't get the downvote. This is a good question.

Comment: Not sure why but my suspicion is that the "look/vibe" of *Supergirl* is significantly different from that of *Superman and Lois*...so they don't want the fortresses to look the same. Certainly there are arguments to be made that they should re-use the set...**if** that is they are actual physical sets and not CGI.

Comment: Screenrant asked the same question - https://screenrant.com/superman-lois-fortress-solitude-supergirl-different-look/

Comment: @Paulie_D Good to see I'm not the only one noticing this.  As for physical vs CGI, the actors on *Supergirl* physically interact with the sets often enough that at least a fair amount of it has to be real.

Comment: Other than "a woman's touch," I can't account for the differences. However, I'm not sure that the storylines in *Supergirl* and *Superman and Lois* are supposed to be contemporary. When Superman has appeared in episodes of *Supergirl* in the past, I don't recall any mention of his marriage to Lois or the twins. This may have been affected by the Crisis storyline reset, though.

Comment: @RobJarvis I don't remember the marriage specifically, but there was talk of Superman and Lois going off to Argo City to have their child (singular), which mainly served the narrative purpose of removing "but why can't Superman come help out with [insert problem here]" as a valid question for a while.  This one child got turned into two, (and apparently moved back by a decade and a half or so!), as a part of the Crisis timeline changes.  But the way John Diggle shows up at the same time he's visiting all the other Arrowverse properties would suggest that it's the same year as the other shows.